# Adobe Reader Updater legitimate?

Tags: security, pdf

I just got the following popup:

[image]

Is this a legitimate update from Adobe?

The reason I'm concerned:

- The Flashback virus started off as a fake Adobe *Flash* update.
- The UI on the application does not look like it is using native components. It seems like it's running Java or something similar.
- I didn't run anything to prompt this. It just popped up on its own.

Other notes:

- This is an actual application (it appears in the dock).
- The application has no about menu.
- I do have Adobe Reader installed, but it wasn't running at the time. (In fact, I haven't launched it in a while.)
- There is nothing related to Adobe Reader (or the updater) in my login items (System Prefs > Users > Login Items).
- The process name shows up as Adobe Reader Updater in Activity Monitor.
- The `Details` link goes to http://www.adobe.com/go/update_details which redirects to http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/release-note/release-notes-acrobat-reader.html (However, that doesn't say much. Malware could just as easily link to the official website in order to appear legitimate.)

Comment: You can always manually install the newest version of Adobe Reader from here: http://get.adobe.com/reader/, this way you'll be sure that is a legitimate version. This said, seems like 10.1.3 was released 6 days ago, but I can't tell if this is a legitimate popup

Comment: The real irony here to me is that the only Adobe Software Updater that [I've ever seen](http://pioneeringsolutions.com/wp-content/plugins/rss-poster/cache/ebb76_eb-flash-auto-updater.png) is DEFINITELY not using "native components". Yes, it is a Windows screenshot, but I guess that's the only place I've ever had to install Adobe products :).

Comment: I don't know whether this is legitimate, but if there is software on your system that could put up that dialog maliciously *then you've already lost* because it's already running — which button you click makes no difference. The only exception is situations like web browsers where the dialog is put up on behalf of a third party which does not yet have access, and then it nearly always will have wording like “Are you sure you want to install/enable/grant/whatever this?” rather than words like this case.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like it is legitimate for the following reasons:

- When I launch Adobe Reader, it automatically updates the UI of the application to tell me that Adobe Reader needs to be closed in order for me to install this update.
- My current version really is one below the one it's asking me to update to (10.1.2).
- Under Adobe Reader's Update preferences, I had it checked to automatically download and prompt me to install updates.
- Adobe's website shows that 10.1.3 really is the latest version.
- When I run Help > Check for Updates, the same Adobe Reader Updater application is launched (or rather focused).

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be a legitimate update- I had gotten the same exact pop up. Even after I went to the official site and downloaded the latest version, that window continued to bug me about updating- it reminded me the same day despite the update. I would not trust it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ask Different! Did you get the exact same pop up from 4 years ago? Please add a screenshot if you see it again. Thanks.